# Qt Android gesture issue

Tags: android, c++, qt, gesture-recognition

Upon writing a simple Android application in Qt, I encountered an uncomfortable dilemma:

I have a subclass of QWidget called PlotView, and have reimplemented the event-function from it:

```
bool PlotView::event(QEvent *event){

    if(event->type() == QEvent::Gesture){
        emit gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
        return true;
    }
    return QWidget::event(event); \\Line A

}
```

Also I have the following lines in the class constructor:

```
this->grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
this->grabGesture(Qt::PanGesture);
this->grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
```

What I find very peculiar is that when running the application like this, it does not recognize any gestures. However, when removing the last line of the function (Line A above), the gestures are suddenly recognized, but the widget is not painted.

Some specs: I am currently running Qt 5.2.0, compiling on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 GT-N8010 running Android 4.1.2.

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I could make this run with both the widget being painted and gesture recognition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems adding the lines

```
this->grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
this->grabGesture(Qt::PanGesture);
this->grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
```

to the parent class constructor fixed the problem.

Comment: How do you fixed it? I try as you said, but it does not run

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on this, but I will try to answer from memory.

As I recall, there was an issue where the parent class event handler did not have any way of handling the touch gestures. Luckily I had the possibility of changing this, and therefore chose to solve my problem in this manner.

Also note that I used Qt 5.2.0. I cannot say for sure whether this solution works in other versions.